# access to com port 12 is denied error in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on inventory control project using RFID. In my C# software i can read tag ID properly.. I have connected my RFID reader to com port 12 of my laptop.. But when i run this software i am getting this error on the screen - 
"access to com port 12 is denied"
And when i get this error, my c# software is not reading RFID tag ID properly.. please help me

Comment: Not clear what you are saying - on the one hand you say that you **CAN** read the tag and then you say that you **CANNOT** - which is it? You may need to make the situation a little clearer

Comment: kk. sorry.. see when i run my software first time it works fine.. I can read RFID tag.. But if i close this software and reexecute or if i switch from one window form to another then i am getting this error..